# Generate a list of functions from a closure

Tags: r, functional-programming, closures

```
power <- function(exp) {
  function(x) {
    x ^ exp
  }
}
funlist <- lapply(2:3, power)
```

Now I would expect that the first element of 'funlist' is a square function and the second is a cube function. However it seems like it just repeats the 'cubing'.

```
> funlist[[1]](5)
[1] 125
> funlist[[2]](5)
[1] 125
```

Is there any way to generate a list of functions from a closure in this way? Or general best practices surrounding a problem that I may want to approach in this way?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the output..  I get 25 for the first one. using `R version 3.2.2`

Comment: @FrankP. What was your previous version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it changed behavior in 3.2.0 is this announcement in the news() file:

> Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce() now
>   force arguments to the functions they apply in order to eliminate
>   undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and variable capture
>   in closures. This resolves PR#16093.

Comment: This answer would be a lot cooler if you used `news(Version == "3.2.0" & grepl("Higher", Text))` to get it.  Haha, just kidding.

Comment: Actually I opened up news in a browser and searched on `force`. So I guess I should have written:......  "Luke, `news()` the 'force'".